# How can I find out the number of tabs at the beginning of each line in a text file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, text-processing

I have a text file, where each line may start with a number of tabs, including no tabs. For example, the first line starts with no tab, the second line with 1 tab, and the third line with 2 tabs:

```
Chapter 1 
    1
        1.1
Chapter 2
    1
        1.1
```

Is it possible to get the number of tabs at the beginning of each line, by using Python?

Comment: This isn't what this site is for, if you want someone to write your ideas then use chatgpt. This site is when you have errors that you don't understand and you have done everything that you know of and it's still there. And to answer your question yes it is possible using Python

Comment: What have you tried so far? It seems reasonable to me that one could split the text of a line into characters and count the initial items in the resulting list to see if they were tabs.

Comment: you can use `for`-loop to work with every line separatelly, and nested `for`-loop to work with every char in line. And you can check char by char if it is tab - and count them, When you get different char then you can use `break` to exit `for`-loop

Comment: eventually you can use `regex` (with `^`) to get tabs at the beginning of lines (probably `^\t*`) and use `len()` to see how long string it found

Answer (score 1):

Using [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall), [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) and [`len`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#len):

```
import re

out = list(map(len, re.findall('^\t*', text, flags=re.M)))
```

Or from a file:

```
with open('file.txt') as f:
    out = list(map(len, re.findall('^\t*', f.read(), flags=re.M)))
```

*Note that the `MULTILINE` (`M`) flag is required to match each line start. Also the use of the zero-or-more quantifier (`*`) ensures matching all starts, even to return an empty string.*

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/IRa2Ju/1)

Regex-less variant with [`itertools.takewhile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile):

```
from itertools import takewhile

out = []
with open('myfile.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        out.append(sum(1 for _ in takewhile(lambda x: x == '\t', line)))
```

Output: `[0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2]`

Used input for the first approach:

```
text = '''Chapter 1 
\t1
\t\t1.1
Chapter 2
\t1
\t\t1.1'''
```

Comment: @JonSG TBH I hadn't really paid attention to the asker's rep. Also, I think the question is overall interesting and potentially useful to others.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `for`-loop to work with every line separately and later use `regex` to search tabs at the beginning of line (ie. `^\t*`), and `len()` to check how long string you found.

```
import re

text = '''Chapter 1 
\t1
\t\t1.1
Chapter 2
\t1
\t\t1.1'''

for line in text.splitlines(): 
    found = re.search('^\t*', line)[0]
    count = len(found)
    print(count)
```

Result

```
0
1
2
0
1
2
```

Or you can use nested `for`-loop to work with every char in line. And you can check char by char if it is tab - and count tabs. When you get different char then you can use `break` to exit `for`-loop

```
text = '''Chapter 1 
\t1
\t\t1.1
Chapter 2
\t1
\t\t1.1'''

for line in text.splitlines(): 
    count = 0
    for char in line:
        if char == '\t':
            count += 1
        else:
            break            
    print(count)
```

Comment: @JonSG because we like/love to solve so easy problems ;)